# sending mail in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

i want to send a mail from a localhost to gmail in asp.net,i already set the ipaddress and the grant permission also,but now if i send the mail, failure sending mail error will occur. how can i solve this.pls anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you set the IP address? You cannot send mail from your localhost to the outside without setting it up as a MX server

Comment: Do you want to TEST sending emails from your asp.net application?

Answer (score 0):

Sending email requires SMTP Server. If you want to use Gmail SMTP Server to send emails from localhost, you need to configure gmail user email, password and SMTP Server. Here is an article that is helpful, disucssing many ways to send emails from ASP.NET.

[Sending Email using C# and ASP.Net 2.0](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/95_Sending_Email_using_C__and_ASPNet_20.aspx)